# nginx proxy_pass redirect everything

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

We have a bunch of services sitting behind an nginx reverse-proxy server
[image]

`foo.com/service1/index.html` gets redirected to `service1/index.html` fine.

but when `service1/index.html` has scripts src like `/js/bar.js`, the browser makes calls to `foo.com/js/bar.js`. I want it to make all the calls to `foo.com/service1/js/*`. How can this be achieved?

Here is a snippet of nginx conf

```
location /service1 {
   proxy_pass http://service1
}

location /js/(.*)$ {
   proxy_pass http://service1/js
}
```

When `service2/js` has some resources, it will redirect to `foo.com/js` and break.
How can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your applications running behind the proxy so that they will generate resource URLs starting with `foo.com/serviceN/js`. The base URL for applications is a configurable item.